# How can I use gofmt to align parameters and assignment?

Tags: go

In a go HTTP server I'm maintaining, using VS Code, as my IDE - the `gofmt` command is executed whenever the file is saved but it doesn't respect manual alignment that I introduce the sake of readability.

For example, I'll have my code like this:

```
subRouter.Handle("/"                    , Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetNamespaces ))).Methods("GET")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}"         , Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetKeys       ))).Methods("GET")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}"         , Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleClearNamespace))).Methods("DELETE")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetObject     ))).Methods("GET")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleTouchObject   ))).Methods("HEAD")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handlePutObject     ))).Methods("PUT")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}"         , Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handlePostObject    ))).Methods("POST")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleDeleteObject  ))).Methods("DELETE")
```

...but `gofmt` will compress it to this:

```
subRouter.Handle("/", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetNamespaces))).Methods("GET")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetKeys))).Methods("GET")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleClearNamespace))).Methods("DELETE")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetObject))).Methods("GET")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleTouchObject))).Methods("HEAD")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handlePutObject))).Methods("PUT")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handlePostObject))).Methods("POST")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}/{objKey}", Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleDeleteObject))).Methods("DELETE")
```

I couldn't see any rule or option for `gofmt` to turn off this particular formatting rule. [And documentation is sparse](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/152qsdk1ay/go-nuts-where-can-i-find-the-gofmt-rules-specifications).

Comment: Gofmt really doesn't have any configuration for its formatting rules.  In fact, that's kinda the _point_, that the formatting is the same everywhere.  Configuring what and how it formats would violate that concept.

Comment: Note, however, that if you really are going for readability, you could try multi-lining the function arguments and see if you prefer that.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#semicolons has a blurb on the rationale behind not allowing configuration of gofmt.

Comment: @Kaedys I understand (and agree with) the idea of a zero-configuration formatting utility to ensure consistency - but I wish I could get it to ignore certain parts of the codebase where humans can format code better than gofmt can (for now).

Comment: That depends very much on your definition of "better". It's purely aesthetic, so there really is no "better", just personal preference. Given what we've seen in every other language - that personal preferences rarely match up from one person to the next - having a single unified format for all developers of the language seems the best compromise. For example, I *personally* find your preferred format harder to read. But I agree with Kaedys - try going multi-line and see if you like that better.

Comment: "Gofmt's style is no one's favorite, yet gofmt is everyone's favorite." -- the point of gofmt is so we don't have to have these discussions, and can all just move on with the same code format. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting that it does format maps this way:

```
m := map[string]http.HandlerFunc{
        "/":            Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetNamespaces)),
        "/{namespace}": Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetNamespaces)),
    }
```

that would be one way to present your routes in a nicer format (then run through map and add them to router).

Alternatively if you wish to preserve this space, you can make a sacrifice of stars and slashes to the [space eater](https://play.golang.org/p/KcfbQQTEpK):

```
subRouter.Handle("/" /*             */, Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetNamespaces))).Methods("GET")
subRouter.Handle("/{namespace}" /*  */, Foobar.NewAuthHandler(http.HandlerFunc(handleGetKeys))).Methods("GET")
```

Or just accept the same colour of bikeshed as everyone else.

Comment: It formats maps that way because successive keys are guaranteed to have the same format (`<key>: <value>,`).  Successive function calls, _even to the same function_, are not.

Comment: (This comment was posted 3 years later...) Thank you for suggesting adding an empty comment because that made it work the way I want to! - though this is a subversion of `gofmt` and it wouldn't surprise me if in future `gofmt` strips out empty comments.